# Time Zone Difference

Tags: apex, visualforce

I creating an event in salesforce and sending the activity date and time from the UI.

It saving the same time in sandbox.I moved the same to production is showing a time difference of -7 hrs

My time zone for both production and sandbox is the same i.e:(GMT-07:00) Pacific Daylight Time (America/Los_Angeles)

but when i query the activity date and time it is showing the current time.

But in the UI it is displaying the wrong time.

"The timezone difference when i creating the record from site Url when i create i record within in salesforce it is saving the current time"

Answer (score 2):

when you will query the time it shows time in UTC,but when it is rendered in UI it converts time according to timezone specified for environment.
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/primitive_data_types.htm

Comment: UI converts it to the user specified time zone which can be found under My Personal Information in the setup, or within the table User.TimeZoneSidKey

Answer (score 0):

The Difference is due site user

My Site user is configured to Greenwich Standard Time

When i changed to PST i was able to store the day in proper format